# IIS reset Job schedule path

Tags: windows, web-services, iis, iis-7, reset

Where can I find that whether iis job has been scheduled or last ran? I checked the task scheduler but it did not lead me to anything. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What’s an IIS job ?

Comment: IIS reset Job sorry for missing out

Comment: I am a dba been assigned to find whether there is any iis reset jobs that runs nightly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Unfortunately, no short and fast way to see when IIS was reset last. This needs a monitoring system in your environment.

**Long Answer**

IIS as the service is controlled by WWW publishing service in Windows Services. Therefore, anytime the service is down, IIS is down (Server reboot, stopping the service manually etc.)

`Service start\stops are logged in Windows event viewer as Service has stopped and Service has started.`

IIS has application pools which are "containers" for websites to run in. These app pools may stop\restart due to variety of reasons.

1. Application Pool was manually reset at some point using IIS Manager.
2. Application Pools are by default set to restart ever 1740 minutes (29 hours). Therefore, any request at that moment of restart is going to receive an error.
3. At times application pools crash due to exceptions in website code.

Just as services Application pool restarts are logged in the Windows Event Viewer

Example:

`A worker process with process id of '1234' serving application pool '{your apppool name}' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed.`

You can also look at the IIS Logs (C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles by default) When ever you see the log header, it means the process was started at that time.